# http リクエストでjson形式でデータを取得したいのですがうまくいきません

Tags: python

当方python3の初心者です。ある取引所の現在の価格を取得したいと思っており、以下のようなコードを記述しているのですが、エラーが出力されてしまい、うまくいきません。

エラー内容：

```
raise JSONDecodeError(errmsg, string, idx)
```

ほかの取引所ではうまくいっているのですが、なぜうまくいかないのでしょうか。ご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

```
import requests

    r=requests.get('https://c-cex.com/t/zny_btc.json')
    j=r.json()
    print (j)
```

Comment: `Wrong address requested` になってます。URLアドレスはあってますか？

Comment: アドレスが間違っていました。ご回答いただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

リクエストURLでコイン(1)とコイン(2)の間が`_`ではなく`-`の間違いじゃないでしょうか。
今回の場合なら`https://c-cex.com/t/zny-btc.json`だと思います。

参考
https://c-cex.com/?id=api

> Request example:
>    https://c-cex.com/t/dash-btc.json

Comment: おっしゃる通り、「-」でうまくいきました。ご指摘いただきましてありがとうございました。